# How to combine CSVs in Python?

Tags: python, csv, merge, data-science

So I have two CSV files, and wish to merge them to create one file. My first CSV file has names and balances from 2018, while the second one has names and balances from 2019.
For Eg

2018

> ABC 123
>
> XYZ 456

2019

> ABC 123
>
> PQR 234

Final Output Should Look Like

> ABC 123 123
>
> XYZ 456 0
>
> PQR 0 234

I just don't understand how to do this with Pandas. I am new to python and this assignment was given this morning. This is something which will work as FULL OUTER JOIN if I was working in SQL, but I have no clue how to implement this in Python

Comment: How is this CSV? There are no commas...

Comment: Can you confirm that your input (and output) files are just space delimited csv? Or can the delimiter be a tab or a variable number of spaces?

Comment: @SergeBallesta they are csvs sorry for formatting my question incorrectly

Answer (score 0):

```
   table :test2018.csv
Name   T1
 ABC  123
 XYZ  456

table test2019.csv
Name   T1
ABC  123
PQR  234





import pandas as pd
    train =pd.read_csv('test2018.csv')
    train2 =pd.read_csv('test2019.csv')
    train.head()
    train2.head()
    t1=pd.merge(train,train2,on='Name',how='outer')
    print(t1)
```

Comment: Please add a reference to your answer